# Magnolia Git Repo Documentation Access

Tags: git, repository, magnolia

Completely new to Magnolia CMS and Git access. I was doing [CMS headless tutorials](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/headless/getting-started-with-magnolia-headless/hello-spa/). However cannot follow it completely because initial steps require to clone a git repository and whenever I try cloning, it asks for git credentials. Is the git repository restricted only to contributors or is there a way to request access to it?

I have tried browsing the Magnolia CMS docs and website however cannot find anything related to it.

[Git Clone Error on Magnolia headless CMS SPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4JSM.png)

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Stack Overflow. To help the community better understand your issue, try posting some more details. You've given a good outline of what the issue is, but maybe if we know what you've tried and the error/warning that shows up when you try to git clone, it would be easier to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you for your reply. I've updated my question and there is a link to the screenshot regarding the error when trying to do git clone.

Answer (score -1):

sorry you are having trouble. Yes, there is an issue with accessing the repository. We're looking into it and will reply as soon as it is resolved. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Your answer looks as support from Magnolia team. Stackoverflow is not a place for such exchange.
However you are welcome to provide a technical answer.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Maurice we have updated the git url's on the tutorial pages. They should work now without you needing any credentials.

Comment: Hello Christopher, thanks for replying, however I'm still unable to clone the repo. See my updated question with the link to the screenshot regarding the error when trying to do git clone. Thank you!